# How to search in all attributes using DSL query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

How to check the value contain a string

Below is sample data. I need to search the any attributes which is `Thomas`

- You can see I only have Thomas in first document. So first document has to return. Basically one document if any search field exists i need to retrieve that document

```
   {
       "id": "Accounting 101",
       "dataproduct": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Thomas Baszo",
           "department": "finance",
           "facutly_type": "part-time",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27,
       "course_publish_date": "2015-01-19",
       "course_description": "Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements"
   }
   
   PUT /data/test/2
   {
       "name": "Accounting 101",
       "room": "E3",
       "professor": {
           "name": "Sachin Baszo",
           "department": "finance",
           "facutly_type": "part-time",
           "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
           },
       "students_enrolled": 27,
       "course_publish_date": "2015-01-19",
       "course_description": "Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements"
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to search on any field.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Thomas"
    }
  }
}
```

> default_field
> (Optional, string) Default field you wish to search if no field is provided in the query string.

Defaults to the `index.query.default_field` index setting, which has a default value of `*`. The `*` value extracts all fields that are eligible for term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then combined to build a query if no prefix is specified.