# How to search multiple string in all attributes using DSL query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-query

I went through link [How to search in all attributes using DSL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286407/how-to-search-in-all-attributes-using-dsl-query)

My requirement is searching multiple string

For one string below is the DSL query

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "string1"
    }
  }
}
```

FOr multiple string can i pass like below

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "string1","string2","string2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(string1 OR string2) AND string2"
    }
  }
}
```

You can have AND/OR combinations. Here, I added an example of `(A OR B) AND C`. Default operator when you specify `"A B C"`, it is `OR`.

There are many options which is supported by `query_string` - Refer the [documentatian](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Comment: FYI, you're missing double quotes around the query string and the last parenthesis is unbalanced

Comment: I am correcting it. Thanks for the help. Good catch @Val

Comment: Does it works for multiple list of dictionaries and in any on filed if 'string1' matches and returns?

Comment: Yes, That's what you referred in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286407/how-to-search-in-all-attributes-using-dsl-query). Unless you change the default field value. it will match on any field

Comment: does it will check description

Comment: What is description? one of your field? then yes